# Alternate text for links in PDFs generated with DITA OT and FOP

Tags: pdf, accessibility, apache-fop, dita, dita-ot

I'm generating PDFs with DITA OT 3.6 and Apache FOP 2.5. For accessibility, we need to provide alternate text for links (such as the table of contents and cross-references). So far, I haven't found a way to do this with <fo:basic-link>. I tried using <xsl:attribute name="fox:alt-text">, but that doesn't work with <fo:basic-link>. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need to provide alternate text on links, they usually have their own text content inside them and also target information.

The Apache FOP docs states that the "fox:alt-text" is used only on fo:external-graphic and fo:instream-foreign-object to provide alternate text:

https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/accessibility.html

Maybe you can try to use a commercial PDF processor like Antenna House which seems to be able to support alternate text on links: https://www.antennahouse.com/tips-tricks/2016/03/pdf-techniques-for-web-content-accessibility-guidelines-2-0